# setTimeout not executing first time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use setTimeout. I want it to execute every five seconds but not immediately when setTimeout is called. I can't get it to work:

```
firsttime = true;
window.setTimeout(function () {
    if (!firsttime) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    firsttime = false;
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: Did you really mean "I ***don't*** want it to work"??

Comment: Your sum total of your code is setting firsttime to false;

Comment: Do you *seriously* want to reload the page every 5 seconds?  If so, I suggest AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` only runs once.

`setInterval` runs every X milliseconds.

```
firsttime = true;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (!firsttime) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    firsttime = false;
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: He is calling `window.location.reload()` inside timeout, `setInterval()` might not really work as expected...

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I assumed the `reload` was just an example, and that he wasn't *really* doing that.

Answer (score 6):

Once you `window.location.reload()` your page, all JavaScript variables and timers are lost. When the page is loaded for the second time, you `firsttime` is `true` again.

So what you are trying to do is: when user first enters the page, refresh it after 10 seconds. Then refresh it every 5 seconds. The problem is: HTTP is statelss, every time user enters the page, it *is* the first time. There is no memory or state in between.

What you can do is:

- use cookies or HTTP session to remember that user already entered the page. The first time you use `setTimeout()` with 10 seconds. On every subsequent entry on that page you use 5 seconds (`setInterval()` is worthless here)
- After entering the `first.html` wait 10 seconds and redirect to `second.html`. Identical, but with hardcoded 5 second delay. Query parameters or hash tags can be used as well to persist state. A little bit hacky though.
- refreshing the whole page once in a while is so 2000-ish. Consider [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) and partial DOM updates.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for setInterval. It takes the same parameters, but executes the callback every X seconds, not once.

Comment: `setInverval()` won't work if he is reloading the page. Well, it will, only once every.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` runs only once and at that point, the condition `(!firsttime)` doesn't hold (as `firsttime` is `true`, so nothing happens.

You may leave this check. The function will **not** load immediately. The first execution will be after the delay specified.

If you're looking for repeated execution, check `setInterval`. But you should realize that `window.location.reload();` reloads the whole page, including the JavaScript in it, so it can only be executed once (then the page is reloaded, intervals are cleared and JS reinitialized, with another timeout instance).

Maybe HTML refresh would be more useful in your case:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=yourwebpage">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!firsttime) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    firsttime = false;
```

This will only execute once because you call the timeout in 5 seconds:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
}, 5 * 1000);
```

When you want it to keep executing every 5 seconds; use setInterval:

```
firsttime = true;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (!firsttime) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
    firsttime = false;
}, 5 * 1000);
```

But then; setTimeout with 10 seconds would be sufficient:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload();
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Because the variable firsttime will reset to true when the page reloads